# mvc3 webgrid checkbox value lost on page change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am using web grid. Now problem is that i have checked some check boxes on my first page. When i go to next page from first page then value of check box lost. How i fix it? For paging i have use this code:-

```
var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canSort: true, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid_Products"); 
@grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid_Products" }, columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(
                   header: "",
                   style: "text-align-center",
                           format: (item) => new HtmlString(Html.CheckBox("select", false, new { id = item.ProductID }).ToString() + "|" + Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ProductID }).ToString()
                                                   )
                ),
                grid.Column("ProductName"),
                grid.Column("UnitPrice")

            )
)
```

Thanks in advances...